# How can I coordinate the ViewPager animation with a custom menu?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, gesture, viewpagerindicator

I have a `ViewPager` with three `Fragments`, but I would like to implement my own custom menu. However, I don't know how can I coordinate the touch of the `ViewPager` gesture, so that the bar underneath my menu is not only animated *between* the two different touches (when I click on a different icon, the bar goes from X to Y), but also *during* the dragging of one fragment towards the adjacent one. In a sense, I would like to (deeply) customize `PagerSlidingTabStrip`.

To be precise, this is the scheme:

[image]

I don't want to use an external library, since I really want to understand how can I coordinate gestures with real-time animations (and not only: go from X to Y in Z milliseconds).

Answer (score 0):

I think a [`TabLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) below your `ViewPager` would accomplish what you're looking for. If you want to build a custom solution, the `TabLayout` [source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.java) is probably a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `TabLayout` under your view pager and coordinate the view pager with your `TabLayout` like.

```
viewPaget.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout))
```